# assign li a background color of my choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some colors on  my server side. I have a list structure in the . When I am loading the jsp I want to assign a particular li a particular color. The color from server side can change as well as which li should be assigned a color depends upon server side so I can't include that color in css rules.

The structure I have is follows

```
 <ul>
  <li id="one" class="liClass" style="background-color:<%=Color %>">..(1)
  <div>...</div>
  <div>....<div>
  <select>...select</select>
  </li>
  <li id="two">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>....<div>
   <select>...select</select>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Can I do something like above?

Also can i have something like a div inside li tag and the div should occupy all inside li.?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: jQuery isn't the answer here if both the LI reference to be coloured, as well as the colour itself are coming from the server, and are available to use when the page renders.

Comment: If you have to assign the color inline then this should work unless a CSS rule overrides it.

Comment: yeah i have tried...but it's not working..

Comment: Did you remember to add the hash (#)? `background-color:#123456`

Comment: Do you want to override the color assigned by JSP or you want to assign the color with JSP?

Comment: @saurabhranu, View the Source code, for that line and post it, so we can see what output you reciving from `<%=Color %>`

Answer (score 1):

in your code  there are syntax errors

```
<li id="one" class="liClass" style="background-color:<%=Color %>">..(1)
  <div>...</div>
  <div>....<div>
  <select>...select</select>
  </li>
```

you used 
 `<div>....<div>` it is incorrect

you used 
`<select>...select</select>` it is incorrect also

an also i think there is html errors in

```
<li id="one" class="liClass" style="background-color:<%=Color %>">..(1) line .
```

please check those errors and correct them first .

**UPDATE**

first correct the HTML and then hard code the `style="background-color:`  and check if it works . then try to add it dynamically .

start simply ok............ (that's my advice).............. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

I would advise against inline styling though. I think it would be more appropriate to define these colors in a stylesheet (using the same serverside method if needed), and then generate a `class="color_class"` inside of the li element

Comment: you should of stopped with just `Yes you can do this` as the `OP` stated: color depends upon server side so `I can't include that color in css rules`